# Modify what Wordpress includes in the RSS <description> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have a Page on a Wordpress website that I want to let people follow for updates using the RSS feed however the  tag of the RSS output doesn't include the content of the page.

How do I modify what is included in the  tag?

I can edit wp-includes/feed-rss.php but I don't know what I'm changing this line to:

`<description><?php bloginfo_rss( 'description' ); ?></description>`

How do I say `'the page content I want to update people on'`?

Comment: What do you want to modify in rss feed? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: When my page is updated I want the RSS <description> tag to include the content of my page.